# Mysql insert a row only if id exist in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 simple table

- table1 -> p_id | s_id
- table2 -> p_id | s_id

The two table are same. **The p_id ai value**.

I would like to insert into the table2 a row, but **only if p_id is exist in table1. This is possible? (MySQL)

```
INSERT INTO table1 (p_id, s_id)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '100', '2') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT p_id FROM table2 WHERE p_id = '100')
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible and (a) pretty trivial (b) depending on where your data comes from (c) you didn't search in SO at all, did you?

Comment: just do a select count(*) from the one. If greater than 0, do the insert. Move onto next thing you need to do.

Comment: Yes I tried to search and found some solutions, but didn't worked for me. I updated my question with the code what I try to use now.

Comment: Why don't you set p_id as a FK of table1. You won't be able to insert a row if the id doesn't refer to a valid id in table1. You will INSERT then fetch the result if you have a constraint integrity error. But I also agree with @Drew. Keep it simple and go ahead

Comment: Well he edited the question since my comment.

Comment: My question was not entirely correct. So still important thing, that the s_id need to equal with a value. In this way the select count will work?

Comment: If you need me to talk you thru it in chat, come to [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) and ping me with an @ sign

Answer (score 5):

You can insert into a table based on any SELECT query. For example:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (p_id, s_id)
SELECT p_id, 2 FROM table1 WHERE p_id = 100;
```

If there are zero rows in table1 with the specified p_id value, this is a no-op. That is, it inserts zero rows into table2. If there is 1 row in table1 with that p_id value, it inserts into table2.

No need for `LIMIT 1` because if p_id is the primary key then there is guaranteed to be only 1 or 0 rows with the given value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`Insert into table2 (p_id,s_id) Select p_id,'2' as s_id FROM table1 where p_id=100 LIMIT 1`